# How to find class of an object?

Tags: c#

I have a method named `A(Object senderObject)` which receives senderObjectas parameter, which is nothing but object of sender. At runtime , I am not sure which class would call this method but what I need is not to just get from which class is it (Using getType) but also to cast it to its real class type and assign to another same class object.

Let me give you an example to clear my question. Suppose if the senderObject is from class A, I need to do:

```
A objAnother = (A)senderObject.
```

Suppose if the senderObject is from class B, I need to do:

```
B objAnother = (B)senderObject.
```

May I know how to do it? I need Dynamic method for the same.

Comment: What are you going to do with the object after that? Do you have an `if` or `switch` statement based on the type of object, or are you assuming that a particular method will exist on all types that are passed in, or something else?

Comment: Is using `generics` an option for you?

Comment: To me your scenario is not clear I understand only is, you will get `sender` object in say X method. Then what? `sender.Ymethod()` inside X method body ?

Comment: Since it is not clear what you want to do afterwards I just can guess: maybe the dynamic keyword helps to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) and [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

```
if (senderObject is A)
{
    // do something
}
```

Or:

```
A a = senderObject as A;

if (a != null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I don't want to write for all the classes. I need dynamic one

Comment: If `A` and `B` share the same base class, you could cast to that.

Comment: @Pratik: How do you mean 'dynamic'?

Comment: Mean I don't need to ad one more if , if I create new class. By putting ifs, we are making it static to those classes only. As I said, I don't know which class would call that method. May be some class from code of my colleagues also.

Comment: And how do you plan to class any method on it if you don't know the type?

Comment: Don't worry about it. I just want this to be done for some purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the is keyword to do this.

```
if (senderObject is ClassA)
{
}
```

Comment: Then how to proceed for Creating another object?

Comment: You can use generics. But fair warning: they are not intended to be used the way you want it.

Comment: Please give few lines as an example.